# time to create topic dynamically by producer in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

what is the latency in creating a new topic dynamically by producer in Kafka? The command line tool takes 1 to 1.5 seconds, what about if it is created dynamically by producer with api call in sending message to broker? Would it be fast or has similar latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same, Both will call zookeeper to create a **Znode**.

This time actually depends on the number of **partitions, replicas and other properties** than **producer vs command line tool**